# Erro de Android Studio: Unable to start activity

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, nullpointerexception, realmdb

Estou fazendo um CRUD básico com o RealmDB. Eu fiz uma lista, e quando algum item dessa lista for selecionado, é para abrir uma Activity de Update, onde dá pra alterar o dado selecionado.
O problema é que a activity "secundária" nem chega a abrir. O Run diz que o problema é uma NullPointerException, mas eu não faço a mínima ideia de onde seja. Já verifiquei cada canto do código

Este é o código da Lista. No final eu coloquei um ClickListener que deveria abrir a nova Activity a partir de uma Intent

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<People> people;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<People> people) {
        this.c = c;
        this.people = people;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return people.size();
        //tamanho da lista
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return people.get(position);
        //pega o item de uma posição específica
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
        //pega a posição de um item específico
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        TextView txtName;
        txtName = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

        People p = (People) this.getItem(position);

        final int numPosition = p.getPeople_id();
        txtName.setText(p.getPeople_name());

        //OnClick
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("numPosition", numPosition);
                c.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

E esse daqui é o código da Activity que eu quero que abra mas não abre

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Realm realm;
    private EditText editNameDetail;
    private Button btnUpdate;
    private People people;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        editNameDetail = findViewById(R.id.edit_nameDetail);
        btnUpdate = findViewById(R.id.btn_update);

        Intent getIntent = getIntent();
        int position = getIntent.getIntExtra("numPosition", 0);

        people = realm.where(People.class).equalTo("people_id", position).findFirst();
        editNameDetail.setText(people.getPeople_name());

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateData();
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateData(){
        realm.beginTransaction();
        people.setPeople_name(editNameDetail.getText().toString());
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

E por fim, esse é o erro que está dando

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.realmtest1, PID: 17712
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.realmtest1/com.example.realmtest1.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.realmtest1.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17712 SIG: 9
```

XML da Activity que não está abrindo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_nameDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_update"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, me dê uma dica por favor. Pode ser que seja algo simples ou pode ser que seja algo complexo, eu não sei.
Obrigado desde já

Comment: Seu layout `activity_main` realmente possui uma `EditText` com o id `edit_nameDetail`? O erro parece ser na linha `editNameDetail.setText(people.getPeople_name());`

Comment: Sim, sim. O XML dessa activity tem um EditText com esse nome. Vou colocar o XML na postagem original tbm, um momento

Answer (score 0):

Consegui arrumar. No começo do projeto eu coloquei "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"
O que não faz sentido, já que a atividade desse projeto remete ao xml "detail_activity", e não ao "activity_main"

Não é possível buscar elementos de uma activity estando em outra!!! Não cometam o mesmo erro que eu